# Comparing one value with another

Tags: python

I get an error when using

```
if ThingOne <= ThingTwo:
```

the error is something about str and int

I don't understand what google told me, is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think you're looking for `<=` or `>=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greater/less than operator needs to be before the equals sign.

What you're trying to do should be `<=`